# Android Studio: Repoen App with Previous Screen

Tags: android

I'm writing an app with 8 different Activities that are all interconnected(accessible from one another). I'm wondering how I can have the app always reopen from a full close (not just home button click but from closing the background activity) with the same screen it was exited from.

For example, from my Splash Screen I navigate to a home screen. From that home screen I navigate to the Settings. Now, I click the multi-tab viewer and close all apps. How can I have Settings(or wherever I had left off) become the launching activity when the app is reopened?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use SharedPreferences to store the class name of the latest Activity. Later, when relaunch, you can redirect to it from the Splash Screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that simply by using SharedPreferences. When you launch an activity, it changes it's last activity value in SharedPreferences to point at that activity.

When you close the app and then reopen it, your Main/Launcher activity (Which may be your Splash Screen) then checks for this value and launches the activity according to this value which represents the last activity the app was on.

Here is the code that would fit the Main/Launcher activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String lastActivity = getDefaults("LAST_ACTIVITY", MainActivity.this);
        Intent intentLastActivity;
        // use an if statement to find out which activity it is


        if(!lastActivity.equals("") || !lastActivity.equals(null)){
            if(lastActivity.equals("home")){
                intentLastActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
            }else if(lastActivity.equals("settings")){
                intentLastActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
            // add more else-if statements for the other activities.
            }
            startActivity(intentLastActivity); // launch the last activity
            finish(); // finish/close the current activity.
        }

}


public static void setDefaults(String key, String value, Context context) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.apply();
}
public static String getDefaults(String key, Context context) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        return preferences.getString(key, null);
}
```

Once that code is placed in your Main/Launcher activity. You can then set this last activity value in SharedPreferences in other activities when they are launched.
Code placed in the other activities (in the onCreate method):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

        // we are at the settings activity. Change last activity value to settings
        MainActivity.setDefaults("LAST_ACTIVITY","settings",this);


}
```

**Luckily the methods to change the last activity are accessible in other activities.**

If you're able to implement this well in your app. It should work as you want it to.
HOPE THIS HELPS!